# Sharepoint list field description not picked up in InfoPath form

Tags: list, infopath

I am trying to ensure that my form (which is based on a sharepoint list) contains some useful hints for the users who will fill in the data in the form. To achieve this, I have created some field descriptions in the sharepoint list. What I was hoping was that when I then create the form in InfoPath, those descriptions would appear alongside the field names in the form. They don't. I have extensively searched the web and haven't been able to find a solution. I should qualify this by mentioning that due to the way our IT department works, I am not allowed access to SharePoint Designer nor would I be permitted to go in and edit the code (even if I knew how).

Hope someone can help.

Kind regards
Nick

Comment: I am assuming that when you say "field descriptions" you mean that you clicked on the existing columns (in List Settings) and added a Description under "Additional Column Settings", correct?

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint designer will not assist you with this.  In order to have the descriptions or screen tips you need to edit each box.

[image]

The screen tip allows you to hover over the box to view the tip or you can use a placeholder that is greyed out to add a tip which is under the data tab within the textbox properties

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are entering the field description of a list entering into a different list and trying to show them on Infopath form.

If I am right for that you can follow below steps to achieve.

- Go to your form list settings.
- Click on fields you want little note and in the field settings page, you will have description field which can be used to shown on a screen.
- This you can repeat for all fields you want.
- From the IE browser you can go to the List settings on the Ribbon.
- You click on "InfoPath Form" to create.
- It will show all fields and with description will be shown.
  You can get the notes as shown on the screen.
  [image]